# How to place a close icon on the top of jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have several jqgdids on my page and wouldlike to make them coseable. So I would like to replace the icon at the right-top corner to an X and bind close event on it. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: place grids into jq UI Dialog, don't provide the grid title property and should work out of the box

Comment: How you imagine an interface which will allows the user to open the closed grid?

Comment: Oleg, I realy only need to close them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to be able to close the grid (hide it) with to give the user the possibility to reopen the grid you can do the following:

1) You can implement closing/hiding the grid inside of `onHeaderClick` callback:

```js
onHeaderClick: function () {
    $(this).closest('.ui-jqgrid').hide('blind', {}, 500);
}
```

2) You can replace the standard minimize icon from the right part of the capture by the following code:

```js
$('#gview_' + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id) + ' .ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close>span')
    .removeClass('ui-icon-circle-triangle-n')
    .addClass('ui-icon-closethick');
```

where `$grid` is defined like `var $grid = $('#list');` and represent the grid. The expression `'#gview_' + $.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id)` will get in the case `'#gview_list'`. The usage of `$.jgrid.jqID($grid[0].id)` could be important only for the case when the grid id ('list' in the example above) contain some [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

The corresponding demo you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CloseGrid.htm).